# Why can the integrate from 2 to x^2 sin(t^3) be written as y/x?

Tags: calculus

Why can the integrate from 2 to x^2 sin(t^3) be written as y/x? I expected the answer to be some cosines....

[image]

Comment: This is just a routine application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The solution substitues $y/x = \int_2^{x^2} \sin(t)^3\mathrm{d}t$ since you are given $y = x \int_2^{x^2} \sin(t)^3\mathrm{d}t$ by assumption.

Comment: Ah, now I see what they were doing, why couldn't I come up with that myself...